# "Failed to create storage area association" when trying to create a shadowcopy on a different disk than the dedicated disk

Tags: windows

It works when trying to create a copy on the local disk ( from D:\ to D:\ lets say) but not when I try to set it to another disk (from D:\ to S:\ for example)

I was expecting to create a shadowcopy on a different disk but was getting the error you see in the screenshot.

Error: Failed to create storage area association. (Error 0x8004231d: 0x8004231d)

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sujD1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was simple.
Make sure that the size you put in the "limit to" is at least 15% of the source disk. So for example set the limit to at least 150GB on a source disk of 1TB.
Normally this should be between 15% and 20%.